# How to use one function for different BehaviorSubjects

Tags: javascript, angular, behaviorsubject

I used to have one banner at the top of the page for all events in my app (like some Errors, Warnings, and Success) and used for that BehaviorSubject.

For example:
in the main app.component.html file I had:

`<baner [alerts]="alerts$ | async"></baner>`
and alerts get from bannerService:

`ngOnInit(): void { this.alerts$ = this.bannerService.alerts$; }`

the service looks next:

```
alertSub$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
alerts$ = this.alertSub$.asObservable();

showWarning(message: string): void {
  const newAlert = { message, type: 'Warning' };
  this.alertSub$.next([...this.alertSub$.getValue(), newAlert]);

  setTimeout(() => this.dismiss(newAlert), 500);
}

dismiss(alert): void {
   const updatedAlerts = this.alertSub$.getValue().filter(alertSub => alertSub !== alert);
   this.alertSub$.next(updatedAlerts);
}

...and so on...
```

So when I wanted to add some warning, I called `this.bannerService.showWarning('some msg')` and everything was fine.

But now I need to add a banner inside another component for its own warnings, and it should be independent. This means that global warnings would be still on the top of the app, but warnings of this component are only inside the component.

I understand, that I should create a new BehaviorSubject, but how to re-use all functions correctly?

For now, I've added to all functions a parameter, that pass proper BehaviorSubject, but in that case, I need to make changes in all places, where bannerService was used.

Service with my new changes:

```
alertSub$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
alerts$ = this.alertSub$.asObservable();

componentSub$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
componentAlerts$ = this.componentSub$.asObservable();

showWarning(message: string, banner: BehaviorSubject<string>): void {
  const newAlert = { message, type: 'Warning' };
  banner.next([...banner.getValue(), newAlert]);

  setTimeout(() => this.dismiss(newAlert, banner), 500);
}

dismiss(alert, banner: BehaviorSubject<string>): void {
   const updatedAlerts = banner.getValue().filter(alertSub => alertSub !== alert);
   banner.next(updatedAlerts);
}

...and so on...
```

Would be really grateful for any idea, on how to use old functions for different BehaviorSubjects.

Comment: a Service can be general for all your app, and we use when define the service {providedIn:'root'}, only in a module (you use providers array), or even in an unique component (also use providers array). Sadly It's not very clear the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action). A [stakcblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xsv5rz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be a bit easier than that. Your `baner` component is responsible of rendering the messages, right? What if you modify this component to take in two instances of `bannerService` instead of just one? Let's suppose this is our `BannerComponent`:

```js
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {
  bannerService: BannerService;
    

  constructor(
    @Host() @Optional() parentBannerService: BannerService,
    @Inject() globalBannerService: BannerService
  ) {
    this.bannerService = parentBannerService ?? globalBannerService;
  }
```

This allows us to ask the injector for an (optional) instance of `BannerService` that is provided by the parent component (the component that renders the `BannerComponent` component).

In case we don't have such a thing, we still want the `BannerService` to be injected from somewhere, hence the second parameter, `globalBannerService`.

Now all that is left for us to do, is to provide a `BannerService` instance from our custom component that displays the banner:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-with-its-own-banner',
  //  template, css, etc
  providers: [BannerService]
})
export class ComponentWithItsOwnBanner {
  // ...
}
```

The template of this component also includes the `banner` component selector:

```html
<baner [alerts]="bannerService.alerts$ | async"></baner>
```

Everything else can stay exactly the same. You don't need to create any additional behavior subjects.